# Get byte data as Uint8List when play audio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, flutter-audioplayers

I'm trying to get byte stream of currenty playing audio. The goals is i want to store every byte data when play to list.  I've try flutter_sound and just_audio, but there is no method to access current byte data on play. any solution for this?